# changing page url without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is this even possible?

Here's the problem:

I have a keyword search with this URL(after searching) : http://localhost/thi/search?keyword=key

Then I have a slider search which uses the AjaxForm plugin (jquery)...

when I perform a slider search, obviously I will still be in the keyword search URL (because the request is sent via ajax)

Is there a way to change the current url to something like http://localhost/thi/search?price=100 (the slider submits via GET with price as a GET variable)

I wish to do so because I want the search results from the slider to be bookmarked...or is there any alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use hash urls (search#price=100) with `window.location.hash` methods. These will get bookmarked and user can navigate through these with back and forward buttons.

Usage sample:

```
<a href="#">100</a>

$('a').click(function() {
    window.location.hash = 'price='+$(this).html();
    return false;
});
```

Will set the url to `search#price=100` without refreshing.

Comment: Will it fire a get on the URL too?

Comment: No, it won't, as hashes are on the current page. If the hash exists, it'd jump to it.

Comment: This will make the page "bookmarkable" but you can't visit that page and have "price=100" sent to the PHP/ASP script that renders the page, you have to fetch it with javascript and then do the AJAX fetching again...

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I'm trying to figure out the same thing. Can you explain how would you use the ajax fetch for getting users to have "price=100" if users want to type it in the url?

Comment: When you load the page, check if `window.location.hash` is not empty. If it has something in it, parse it, then make an appropriate AJAX request based on the variables.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing I can suggest for this would be to use the hash in the url. This will allow users to bookmark the url and still keep state when they come back. The other benefit is that you can change the hash without refreshing the page.

So your url would look something like...http://localhost/thi/search?keyword=key#price=100

The JQuery Address plugin would work really well for this.

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Answer (score 3):

With HTML5 it's possible. Use window.history.pushState().

Example :

```
if(currentHref!=window.location){
    window.history.pushState({path:currentHref},'',currentHref);    
}
```

Details and explanations : http://tinywall.info/2012/02/22/change-browser-url-without-page-reload-refresh-with-ajax-request-using-javascript-html5-history-api-php-jquery-like-facebook-github-navigation-menu/