# Stop reload when using window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click of a button I am changing `window.location.href`, i.e. I am adding one query string parameter. This causes the page to be refreshed (as I am changing `window.location.href`).
I want to know is it possible to stop this page refresh and append the query string in the url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You can change the `#hashstring`, but changing the query string results in a reload.

Answer (score 6):

Any assignment of new values to the location object from JavaScript will load a new page.

It is possible to change the hash value without refreshing the page but not the query string.

See this thread: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=552076

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898331/changing-page-url-without-refreshing-page/1898340#1898340), maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you append a #hashstring the page will not reload.  In addition, if the user hits the back button on the browser it will remove the #hashstring.  The #hashstring can be useful for saving state in the URL bar without causing a reload and can be coupled with ajax calls.

It's important to note that the #hashstring will not be sent to the server and is only visible to the web browser.  For example:  http://example.com/#blah

Will generate a http request that looks like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

The #blah does not get sent down to the server by the browser.

Comment: I didn't know browsers don't send the hash to servers. Interesting. +1, and welcome to Stack Overflow.