# localhost changes without refreshing

Tags: html, css, dom, xampp, localhost

I saw that everyone who teaches web dev in youtube uses localhost that "refreshes" website when changes in code are made. How is that made?

I know how to create localhost using xampp but can seem to find information how to make live updates or i'm just blind...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898331/changing-page-url-without-refreshing-page

Comment: I know that some plugins like http://livereload.com/ watches the local folder and reload the page, when files inside the folders change.

Comment: You can use "brackets" IDE

Answer (score 1):

I use [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) for livereload. It could be used without any build system or task runner like grunt and your site could be watched on any device. You just need to have installed nodejs and npm to install it.